# deviceQuery program -  number of multiprocessors = 0

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have executed the deviceQuery program in the CUDA SDK. The number of mutiprocessors and cores are 0 in the file that I'm sure that is not true. 
What the reasons can be?

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

There are 3 devices supporting CUDA

Device 0: "Tesla C2050"
CUDA Driver Version:                           4.10
CUDA Runtime Version:                          4.10
CUDA Capability Major revision number:         2
CUDA Capability Minor revision number:         0
Total amount of global memory:                 2817982464 bytes
Number of multiprocessors:                     0
Number of cores:                               0
Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
Total number of registers available per block: 32768
Warp size:                                     32
Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 65535
Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
Clock rate:                                    1.15 GHz
Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes
Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
Integrated:                                    Yes
Support host page-locked memory mapping:       No
Compute mode:                                  Default 
(multiple host threads can   use    this device simultaneously)
```

Comment: Post the output from deviceQuery.

Comment: @ Tom: As you can see, everything except the number of multiprocessors and the number of cores is true.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that:

- Uninstall all the old graphics drivers and install the latest NVIDIA graphics drivers.
- Uninstall all the old CUDA toolkits and install the latest CUDA toolkit.

Comment: DeviceQuery already says it detected 3 graphics cards. So I am not sure if what you are saying will affect the cores and multiprocessor counts.

Comment: Pavan: When he originally posted the question, he had NOT shared the output of deviceQuery. I see that he has put it now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update your nvidia drivers to the latest available and then reboot.  If that doesn't fix it, please run the following commands and post the output:

```
uname -a
nvidia-smi -q
lspci
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ldd /path/to/deviceQuery
ldconfig -p
devicequery (with all output, not just the card in question)
```